# How can I run code any time part of an Ember view is rerendered?

Tags: ember.js

My goal is to have a Facebook like button that can conditionally appear in an Ember view. My template is:

```
{{#if condition}}
    Click Like: <div class="fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/obnob" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
{{else}}
    Nothing to like here!
{{/if}}
```

If `condition` changes during the life of the page, the HTML code for the like button will be inserted and removed accordingly. The problem is that if the div of the like button is inserted after the page has loaded, the Facebook JavaScript library will not parse it and turn it into a like button. To do this you must call `FB.XFBML.parse()`.

I tried using the `didInsertElement()` hook of `Ember.View`, but this runs only when the view is first inserted into the DOM, not after it is already there.

I tried to fix this by adding a script tag to the template:

```
<script>FB.XFBML.parse();</script>
```

This failed because the script tage interferes with Metamorph's script tags.

### Questions

1. Does Ember have a hook for running code anytime Metamorph changes an Ember view that has already been rendered?
2. How do you write script tags in an Ember template without it clobbering Metamorph's tags?

Comment: Did you try to wrap FB like button into a typed view and define `didInsertElement` especially for it?

Comment: How about "willRerender" http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.Binding.html#doc=Ember.View&method=willRerender&src=false

Comment: @s.ermakovich What is a typed view?

Comment: @Rajat I don't think `willRerender()` will work because I need a hook that runs after not before the rerender.

Comment: @hekevintran Sorry, maybe "typed view" is not an appropriate term. Please, find my answer below. I've explained it there in more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a view for your button, and do any custom logic in the `didInsertElement` function. Example:

```
{{#if condition}}
    {{view App.LikeButton}}
```

...

```
App.LikeButton = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'like-button',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        //apply you custom logic here
    }
})
```

`didInsertElement` function will be called each time after view is rendered and added to the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

You can observe variables inside your view. So you would do

```
App.View = Ember.View.extend({
    conditional: null,

    _conditionalChanged: function() {
        console.log('conditional changed');
    }.observes('conditional')
})
```

And this would allow you to fire code as your conditional changed.

That said, based on your original problem I do not think you should be using a conditional  to manage state. You should look at using a [StateManager](http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.StateManager&src=false) inside your view. This way, as the state of your facebook button changes different actions/events can fire. In fact, you should have a totally separate view responsible for setting up the facebook button.

Comment: some typo error : it should be observes('conditional') not observers