# Using ember.js, how do I get notified when a CollectionView is re-rendered?

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I've a `CollectionView` in ember.js.

Initially, lets say the `content` property is bound to an array which had a few elements. The CollectionView would render those elements, and once they are in the DOM, `didInsertElement` shall be called, firstly for each of the childViews, and finally for the `CollectionView` itself.

Let's suppose `content` changes (e.g. new items added, or array replaced entirely). The `CollectionView` would append new children, or replace the children altogether. The DOM is accordingly updated. But there's no `didInsertElement` called for the `CollectionView`.

I want to run some custom JS after all the changes to the DOM have been made. Something like a didRerenderElement or didUpdateElement hook.

**What have I tried but doesn't work?**

1. I can't put this code in `didInsertElement` of CollectionView, because that is not fired each time the array changes and DOM updates.
2. I tried observing `content`, but the observer would always fire *before* actual DOM update happens.
3. I tried observing `childViews`, but the case is similar.

One obscure solution that worked for me was this:

```
App.MyCollectionView = Ember.View.extend({
  childrenReady: 1, // anything, value doesn't matter

  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function () {
      this.get('parentView').notifyPropertyChange('childrenReady');
    }
  }),

  childrenGotReady: function () {
    if (this.get('childViews').everyProperty('state', 'inDOM')) {
      // run that custom JS code here (e.g. apply jQuery masonry to the elements)
    }
  }.observes('childrenReady')      

});
```

But this is too obscure, and prone to other issues as well.

I've read this: [How can I run code any time part of an Ember view is rerendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119561/how-can-i-run-code-any-time-part-of-an-ember-view-is-rerendered) but that doesn't apply to `CollectionView`s.

I'm running into this in many parts in my app, and I really expect emberjs to have a standard way for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example observer that watches an array of child elements, and calls back when all of them fire their didInsertElement.

```
addOnDidInsertObserver: function(children, callback) {
    var options = {
        willChange: function() {},
        didChange: function(children, removing, adding) {
            var insertedChildren = [];
            adding.forEach(function(added) {
                var onInsertElement = function() {
                    // remove this call back now (cleanup)
                    added.off('didInsertElement', onInsertElement)
                    // capture the child
                    insertedChildren.push(added);
                    // if all of the new children are rendered, fire
                    if (insertedChildren.length == adding.length) {
                        callback(insertedChildren);
                    }
                };

                added.on('didInsertElement', onInsertElement);
            });
        }
    };

    children.addEnumerableObserver(this, options);
    return {'context':this, 'children':children, 'options':options};
}

removeOnDidInsertObserver: function(observer) {
    observer.children.removeEnumerableObserver(observer.context, observer.options);
},
```

Comment: can you help me on how to add this observer to my CollectionView? On what do I call addOnDidInsertObserver function? or maybe you can point me to right page in the docs...

Comment: this works. I also added some timeouts so that I get one callback instead of 10 in succession. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

didInsertElement should work for collectionView as well.[Source](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html#event_didInsertElement). But the childViews property of a CollectionView should not be directly manipulated. Instead, add, remove, replace items from its content property. This will trigger appropriate changes to its rendered HTML. Also calls didInsertElement.

Comment: didInsertElement is called only once for the `CollectionView`. Any changes to the `content` doesn't call it again. And that makes sense too.